# raster to point conversion in python using Arcmap tool called raster to point

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a multiple raster images in .tif format and i want to convert raster files to point which is basically a point shape file. I tried with the following code, it wont work.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
# Set environment settings
env.workspace = r"E:/Soil Moisture/SM Final"
# Set local variables

    outpoint = r"E:/wallace/Soil Moisture/SM Final/rast_point/"
    field = "VALUE"

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license

    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Get a list of the rasters in the workspace  

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

# Loop through the list of rasters  

    for inRaster in rasters:

      # Set the outputname for each output to be the same as the input  
    outpoint = outpoint + "\\" + inRaster 


    # Process: raster to popint  


     arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(inRaster, outpoint, field)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your code indented exactly as displayed in your StackOverflow post? What did you expect from your code and what did it do instead?

Comment: you need to fix the indentation on this, it's impossible to tell what the problem is.  Also explain the problem more in depth, what is going wrong? How is it different than what you expect?

Comment: FYI, for ArcGIS Python stuff, http://gis.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit. But in this case it looks like your problem isn't ArcGIS-specific, you're just indenting your Python code incorrectly.